# in React component have this error: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have this error in React when I try to use HTML5 Canvas drawImage and want to change page from Canvas page to another:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

and here is error https://www.useloom.com/share/3c233254114a45c2933068cc2324c579

What is wrong in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add the code snippet generating the error. You can find all the info to include with your question here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To me the Error message is pretty clear: whatever you pass to `drawImage`, it seems to be no Image. Did you check what object you pass, when this error occurs?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing some code. From the error log, it appears you are looking for an image in your document, and the id of the image is contained in variable "image". But I can't help you more than this without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it was necessary to check is there image or no and call drawImage() in case if there is an image. Here is my code

```
    let img = document.getElementById('imageId');
    if(img){
        ctx.drawImage(img, this.x + 5, this.y - 11)
    }
```